# raspberry pi uvcdynctrl focus control missing for quickcam 9000 pro

Tags: raspberry-pi, webcam, raspbian, setfocus, v4l2

I have a Logitech QuickCam 9000 Pro (V-UBM46) and I cannot control the focus from my RaspberryPi (all packages up to date).

When I list the available webcam controls with uvcdynctrl

```
uvcdynctrl -d /dev/video0 -c
Listing available controls for device /dev/video0:
  Brightness
  Contrast
  Saturation
  White Balance Temperature, Auto
  Gain
  Power Line Frequency
  White Balance Temperature
  Sharpness
  Backlight Compensation
  Exposure, Auto
  Exposure (Absolute)
  Exposure, Auto Priority
```

the focus control is missing. However, when I run the same command on my Ubuntu 13.04 machine, the focus command is present and I can use it.

```
uvcdynctrl -d /dev/video1 -c
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 private control ID encountered: 0x0A046D04 (V4L2_CID_PRIVATE_BASE + 33844484)
Listing available controls for device /dev/video1:
  Brightness
  Contrast
  Saturation
  White Balance Temperature, Auto
  Gain
  Power Line Frequency
  White Balance Temperature
  Sharpness
  Backlight Compensation
  Exposure, Auto
  Exposure (Absolute)
  Exposure, Auto Priority
  Focus
  Focus (absolute)
  LED1 Mode
  LED1 Frequency
  Disable video processing
  Raw bits per pixel
```

I have checked the versions for libwebcam0, uvcdynctrl, uvcdynctrl-data, libv4l-0 and they are all up to date to the same version on both the RaspberryPi and Ubuntu. The only difference is libv4l-0 where the version on Ubuntu is 0.8.9-4 and the RaspberryPi is 1.0.0-1.

Is there perhaps another package or driver that is missing or outdated on the RaspberryPi? How do I get the Raspbian to "see" the focus control?

Comment: Same here: uvcdynctrl list more controls (including Pan and Tilt) on a Ubuntu 11.04 (kernel 2.6.38 i386) than on a Debian 7.7 (kernel 3.2.0 ARM). Versions of `libwebcam0`, `uvcdynctrl`, `libv4l-0`, `setpwc` and `` are always at least the same (and sometimes higher on Debian).

Answer (score 4):

I have the RaspberryPi Model B running Octopi on it. 
I figured out an easy solution for our problem. It works flawlessly for my Pi.
Hope it works on yours too.

1. sudo apt-get install uvcdynctrl
2. sudo apt-get install guvcview
3. sudo guvcview
4. unplug and replug the webcam

After this four steps uvcdynctrl -c shows Focus, Led and more options available.